# Angular code compiles fine but getting many red lines in VS Code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-material

I have imported a project in my system. Though I am able to compile and run the project, still I am getting red lines for modules and directives.

[image]

I have imported the necessary modules in the imports and components are also part of that module.

I have checked the versions too, on other system same code is working fine.

I have also restarted the vs code multiple times.